# How to use Coder with Drush?

Tags: drush

I have unsuccessfully attempted to find how to use the Coder module with Drush. Does anyone know how should I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`coder.drush.inc` exists in module, so yes, it can. Only command available is `coder-format`. Module provides following examples:

```
  'drush coder-format sites/all/modules/coder/coder.module' => 'Re-format coder.module according to Drupal coding standards.',
  'drush coder-format --undo sites/all/modules/coder/coder.module' => 'Restore coder.module from coder.module.coder.orig backup file (if existent).',
  'drush coder-format sites/all/modules/coder' => 'Recursively re-format Coder module files according to Drupal coding standards.',
  'drush coder-format --undo sites/all/modules/coder' => 'Recursively restore Coder module files from *.coder.orig backup files (if existent).',
```

Comment: So there is no command depicting the warnings?

Comment: @PotneySwitters I told you what file to check. Last time I checked it, there was none.

Comment: yea ok, sorry for spamming!

Answer (score 2):

Here are simple steps to install [Coder](https://www.drupal.org/project/coder) ([GitHub](https://github.com/klausi/coder)) and review your coding standards.

### 8.x-2.x

Which can be used for both Drupal 8 & 7 code checks as well.

#### Installation

Recommended process of installation is by using Composer (similar to  `drush`).

```
COMPOSER_BIN_DIR=~/bin composer global require drupal/coder
```

<sup>Change `COMPOSER_BIN_DIR` to where you want to install it (e.g. `~/bin` to install locally or `/usr/local/bin` to install globally).</sup>

Then we need to load the PHP_CodeSniffer Sniff rules, e.g.:

```
phpcs --config-set installed_paths ~/.composer/vendor/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer
```

#### Usage

To check Drupal coding standards and best practices:

```
phpcs --standard=Drupal,DrupalPractice --extensions=php,module,inc,install,test,profile,theme,js,css,info,txt,md /path/to/module
```

Which is equivalent to `drush` command:

```
drush dcs --extensions=<php,module> <path>
```

which will execute `PHP_CodeSniffer` with Drupal Coding Standards on a particular directory.

To automatically fix the coding standards, use:

```
phpcbf --standard=Drupal --extensions=php,module,inc,install,test,profile,theme,js,css,info,txt,md /file/to/drupal/example_module
```

See: [Command Line Usage](https://www.drupal.org/node/1587138)

### 7.x-2.x

#### Installation

```
drush -vy dl coder-7.x-2.x --destination=~/.drush
```

#### Usage

```
drush coder --reviews=all --severity=major --no-empty .
```

<sup>Check `drush help coder` for more information.</sup>

However this branch is frozen, so it's advised to use 8.x-2.x instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are submodules of Coder that contain the other Drush commands. Coder review is the one you want I think and provides:

```
drush coder-review [theme/module name] --minor
```

See coder/modules/coder_review/coder_review.drush.inc and coder_sniffer for more.